# Why can't stdout from calling c library printf in asm be piped to other programs?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, nasm

I have written a simple NASM program:

**printtest.asm**

```
section .data
str_out db "val = %d",10,0

section .text

global main

extern printf

main:

    PUSH 5
    PUSH DWORD str_out
    CALL printf
    ADD ESP, 8
    MOV EAX, 1
    INT 80h
```

I am linking and creating an executable with the following commands:

```
nasm -f elf -l printtest.lst printtest.asm
gcc -o  printtest printtest.o
```

When linked and executed, this prints "val = 5" to the console no problem. As far as I'm aware, calling `printf` by default writes on `stdout`. So why when I try and pipe this to another program does the other program seem to receive no input?

E.g

```
./printtest | cat
```

Seems to do nothing

I am sure I am fundamentally misunderstanding something here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C stdio functions may be buffered by default, so writing to stdout with `printf` doesn't always actually output anything -- sometimes it just writes to the buffer, awaiting a subsequent flush.  Often times, whether a given stdio stream is buffered or not depends on whether it is connected to a terminal or a pipe or a file or something else.

When you call the exit system call (as you do), any data still in buffers will be lost.  If you instead call the C library `exit` function, it will flush all buffers before actually exiting.

Comment: Would `return 0;` from main() accomplish the same thing? Just curious (and I'm not in a position where I can this this right now).

Comment: Should do.  Note that writing your own `main` in asm and then calling the C library is not guarenteed to be safe -- some C implementations rely on special code added to `main` by the compiler to initialize the standard library properly.  Linux should be fine, however.

Comment: Generally not an issue on Linux as generally runtime is initialized before the call to _main_ with all the `libc` versions I have encountered on that platform. This includes C++. Windows on the other hand may require the `ctor` startup code to be called (for static global objects) inside _main_ . (as an example of what you describe) if using C++. This is heavily dependent on the C/C++ runtime library being used.

Comment: Also, in ELF, IIRC, a .so can define `_init` and `_fini` functions (explicit names) and ELF loader (e.g. `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`) will call them when it loads/unloads the .so respectively.  When you use gcc to link an executable, it includes `crt0.o` which has the `_start` symbol which gcc tells ld is the "start symbol" [transfer control to after loading]. `_start` is what calls `main` after setting up a few things and _may_ be what calls the functions specified with ctors/dtors attributes.  Likewise, for .so _init-->ctors, _fini-->dtors.  Or ... ctors/dtors handled by ELF loader.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: gcc's `main` aligns the stack by 16.  If the C runtime stuff that calls main hasn't done that already, you'll be breaking the ABI.  (Which will only matter if anything ever calls a function that actually faults if the stack isn't aligned, e.g. uses alignment-required SSE insns to load or store on the stack.)  But yes, returning from `main` will do the trick here, to answer Keithmo's question.